# First order ordinary differential equations help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) $x'=x\tan(t)-2\sin(t)$ for $-\pi/2<t<\pi/2$

b) $x'=\frac{tx^2-tx}{1+t^2}$, $x(t)\neq 0$ for all t.

Any hints on how to proceed?
For b) I tried separating $x$; $$\frac{1}{x^2-x}x'=\frac{t}{1+t^2}$$but this give me $$\ln \frac{|x-1|}{|x|}=\frac{1}2\ln|t^2+1|$$ which will lead me to exponentials and I doubt that I'm on the right track.

For a) I'm really stuck. Since there's  $2\sin(t)$ I'm assuming $$2\sin x=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}$$ might com in to play? But I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)**

$$x'-x\tan t=-2\sin t$$

$$x'\cos t-x\sin t=-2\sin t\cos t$$

$$(x\cos t)'=-\sin (2t)$$

What you've done for **(b)** seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a): use 'integrating factor'. You can write the equation as $(x(t)\cos \, t))'=-(2\sin \, t )(\cos \, t)$ from which you can find $x$ by just integrating both sides.

For b) what you have done is fine.